# Why can Rolfsen use Van Kampen? (Knots and Links)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am having some difficulty with Rolfsen's derivation of the Wirtinger presentation of a knot in "Knots and Links" (pages 56 to 60). The basic setup is illustrated below.[image]

The proof begins as follows.

[image]

Yet according to Rolfsen's exposition of Van Kampen's theorem (on pages 369 to 372), we require $A, B_1, ..., B_n, C$ to be open. Clearly they are not.

I am new to algebraic topology, so I am probably missing something terribly obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Rolfsen is sloppy a bit here. Instead of closed $C$, he needs to take its small open neighborhood $U$ which is homotopy-equivalent to $C$. This is a common abuse of terminology, you will have to get used to it.

Comment: So Van Kampen’s theorem works when all the sets are deformation retracts of open sets?

Comment: @Jephph You can run into trouble with that (there's an example of a cover of $S^1$ by intervals where the van Kampen theorem is false). A criterion I know that works is that all the sets are subcomplexes of a CW/simplicial/delta complex, and so all the intersections are subcomplexes, too.

Comment: KEY POINT: Let $U$ be an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $K$ for $\epsilon$ very small. Then $\mathbb{R}^3 - K$ deformation retracts onto $\mathbb{R}^3 - U$, so both spaces share the same fundamental group. Although it is not mentioned, Rolfsen is working with the latter space. As other commenters have pointed out, he also does not mention that he is working with $\epsilon$-neighbourhoods of $A, B_1, ..., B_n, C$ (for $\epsilon$ very small), rather than the closed sets themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask in the comments whether Van Kampen's Theorem works when all the sets in the given collection of subsets are deformation retracts of open sets. That's not quite enough, though.

Besides the hypothesis that each set in the given collection of subsets is open, every other hypothesis of Van Kampen's Theorem is a statement regarding properties of certain subcollections of the whole collection of subsets, specifically properties regarding: the path connectivity and fundamental group of the intersection of each such subcollection; and the inclusion induced homomorphism from the fundamental group of that intersection into the fundamental group of each subset of the subcollection.

So you will be fine if, in addition to requiring that each original set being a deformation retract of some corresponding open set, you also require that the intersection of each relevant subcollection of the original sets is a deformation retract of the intersection of the corresponding subcollection of open sets.

This extra requirement is true, for example, if your original collection consists of subcomplexes of some CW complex structure, as alluded in the comment of @KyleMiller.